# Compression array values from input in database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I use of jQuery add new input, each row in table=>tr containing is of several input, and i want add data araye in database as:

```
<table>
tr 1: <tr>
<input name="you[]" value="Translate">
<input name="you[]" value="Searches">
<input name="you[]" value="Email">
</tr>
<br>
tr 2: <tr>
<input name="you[]" value="Phone">
<input name="you[]" value="Chat">
<input name="you[]" value="Business">
</tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PvCuA/)

"value tr 1 is": **Translate** & **Searches** & **Email**
"value tr 2 is": **Phone** & **Chat** & **Business**

I have tow question:
**Q1:** how insert all value array in "tr 1" and "tr 2" together in a row of database table?

**Q2:** how can select (`select * from my_table ....`) only first part values("tr 1 =  'Translate'" and "tr 2 = 'Phone'") by `foreach` of database table?

I want output this: **Translate** & **Phone**

Comment: Can you please clarify the second question?

Comment: `<br>` and text inside a `<table>` but not a `<th>` or `<td>` is ill-formed.

Comment: I don't think that this question is specific enough for SO, which invites questions about programming languages rather than requests to teach approaches for such broad problem specifications. A chatroom might be better suited to this line of inquiry -- and we have many here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will fit to your question

**A1:**

```
// make data to be fit in your database
$you= $_POST['you']; // or $this->input->post('you') In CodeIgniter
$you_chunk= array_chunk($you, 3);
$datayou= "";
foreach( $you_chunk as $youpart ){
   $datayou.= implode(",", $youpart);
   $datayou.= "&";
}

$datayou= substr($datayou, 0, -1); // Output: Translate,Searches,Email&Phone,Chat,Business    

// Insert Data into database
```

**A2:**

```
// Grab data from database
// $getyou= Translate,Searches,Email&Phone,Chat,Business

// Parse Data for grab only first values
$parseyou= explode("&", $getyou);
foreach( $parseyou as $partyou ){
   $firstyou= strstr($partyou, ',', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
   echo $firstyou . "<br/>";
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, you can use the jQuery serialize() function.

Adding a class to your differents fields can help.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>tr 1:</th>
        <td><input name="Translate" value="Translate" class="fields_1"></td>
        <td><input name="Searches" value="Searches" class="fields_1"></td>
        <td><input name="Email" value="Email" class="fields_1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>tr 2: </th>
        <td><input name="Phone" value="Phone" class="fields_2"></td>
        <td><input name="Chat" value="Chat" class="fields_2"></td>
        <td><input name="Business" value="Business" class="fields_2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then

```
var data1 = $('input.fields_1').serialize();
var data2 = $('input.fields_2').serialize();
```

or `var data = $('input').serialize();`

see the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: serialize in jquery only work inside tag <form>, how is insert and select value array on database with php ?

Comment: @Jennifer Anthony Just wrap the input inside a `<form>` tag and give an `id` attribute that represents the table row number. http://jsfiddle.net/PvCuA/1/

Comment: @Jennifer: Why do you have `input` without `form`?